# fatal error: stddef.h: No such file or directory, but the file was in gcc include folder

Tags: gcc, makefile

I'm trying to cross-compile SPL with riscv64 GCC.
but something wrong with it.

how can I solve this?

thanks.

error as follow:

```
nihao@f857f8f304e4:~/sdk/tina-d1-open_new/sun20i_d1_spl$ make CROSS_COMPILE=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu- p=sun20iw1p1 mmc
===This not's tina environment, use command make.===
sh /home/nihao/sdk/tina-d1-open_new/sun20i_d1_spl/tools/generate_hash_header_file.sh > /home/nihao/sdk/tina-d1-open_new/sun20i_d1_spl/include/commit_info.h.tmp
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
if [ -r /home/nihao/sdk/tina-d1-open_new/sun20i_d1_spl/include/commit_info.h ] && cmp -s /home/nihao/sdk/tina-d1-open_new/sun20i_d1_spl/include/commit_info.h /home/nihao/sdk/tina-d1-open_new/sun20i_d1_spl/include/commit_info.h.tmp; then rm -f /home/nihao/sdk/tina-d1-open_new/sun20i_d1_spl/include/commit_info.h.tmp; else echo '  UPD     /home/nihao/sdk/tina-d1-open_new/sun20i_d1_spl/include/commit_info.h'; mv /home/nihao/sdk/tina-d1-open_new/sun20i_d1_spl/include/commit_info.h.tmp /home/nihao/sdk/tina-d1-open_new/sun20i_d1_spl/include/commit_info.h; fi
make -C /home/nihao/sdk/tina-d1-open_new/sun20i_d1_spl/nboot mmc
  CHK     /home/nihao/sdk/tina-d1-open_new/sun20i_d1_spl/include/config.h
  CHK     /home/nihao/sdk/tina-d1-open_new/sun20i_d1_spl/autoconf.mk
make -C /home/nihao/sdk/tina-d1-open_new/sun20i_d1_spl/arch/riscv/cpu/riscv64/
In file included from /home/nihao/sdk/tina-d1-open_new/sun20i_d1_spl/include/linux/types.h:6,
                 from /home/nihao/sdk/tina-d1-open_new/sun20i_d1_spl/include/common.h:11,
                 from arch_timer.c:9:
/home/nihao/sdk/tina-d1-open_new/sun20i_d1_spl/include/arch/riscv/asm/types.h:31:10: fatal error: stddef.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stddef.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/home/nihao/sdk/tina-d1-open_new/sun20i_d1_spl/mk/config.mk:110: arch_timer.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:108: /home/nihao/sdk/tina-d1-open_new/sun20i_d1_spl/arch/riscv/cpu/riscv64/libarch.o] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:83: mmc] Error 2

#### make failed to build some targets  ####
```

the gcc include folder:

```
nihao@f857f8f304e4:~/sdk/tina-d1-open_new/sun20i_d1_spl$ riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc --print-file-name=include
/home/nihao/sdk/tina-d1-open_new/lichee/brandy-2.0/tools/toolchain/riscv64-linux-x86_64-20200528/bin/../lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/8.1.0/include
```

the stddef.h was in the folder:

```
nihao@f857f8f304e4:~/sdk/tina-d1-open_new/sun20i_d1_spl$ ls /home/nihao/sdk/tina-d1-open_new/lichee/brandy-2.0/tools/toolchain/riscv64-linux-x86_64-20200528/bin/../lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/8.1.0/include
float.h  gcov.h  iso646.h  omp.h  openacc.h  riscv-vector.h  stdalign.h  stdarg.h  stdatomic.h  stdbool.h  stddef.h  stdfix.h  stdint-gcc.h  stdint.h  stdnoreturn.h  unwind.h  varargs.h
```

Comment: Most people have no idea what SPL is. You have some kind of makefile that does not show commands that it executes, so what exact command has failed is unknown. Maybe it ran `gcc` with `--sysroot`, or with `--nostdinc`, or who knows what.

Comment: More clearly: find out why your makefile doesn't actually print any of the commands it runs, and fix that so you can see the compiler command line make invoked, then if you still don't understand it edit your question and include it.  The way to do this depends on the makefile environment you have so we can't really help.  Sometimes you can add `V=1` or `VERBOSE=1` or something like that; other times not.